# Dynamic Update query

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, resultset

I need to create a dynamic query that updates a row and gives the user an input window for every column exists in that row and after that insert these values in a query.

I just don't know how to do that as of now since I am new to programming.

Here is my code:

```
try {
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
  c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
  c.setAutoCommit(true);
  System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
  stmt = c.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tablename);
  ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
  //Grabs the first,second and third column name which only is used if you are deleting   from the SPJ table.
  FirstColumn = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
  SecondColumn = rsmd.getColumnName(2);
  ThirdColumn = rsmd.getColumnName(3);
  //Changes the query depending on what table you have chosen
  if(tablename.equals("SPJ")) {
    query = "UPDATE "+ tablename +" WHERE " + FirstColumn + " = '" + row1 + "' AND " +  SecondColumn + " = '" + row2 + "' AND " + ThirdColumn + " = '" +row3+"'" ;

} else {
        query = "UPDATE "+ tablename +" WHERE " + FirstColumn + " = '" + row + "'  VALUES("+values+")";
  }
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
  Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];
for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; ++i) {
row[i - 1] = rs.getString(i); // Or even rs.getObject()
}
// runs the query.
  stmt.executeUpdate(query);
//closes connections
  stmt.close();
  c.close();
```

I tried this which gives me an inputpanel for every column and puts it into the array but i get an sql syntax error near WHERE? :/

```
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
  Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];
for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; ++i) {
row[i-1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert value: "+i); // Or even rs.getObject()
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));

}
}
```

Comment: You should add a JDBC tag.

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong UPDATE syntax. You should use something like this:

> UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1,column2=value2,... WHERE
>   some_column=some_value;

See this link for more examples about UPDATE: [SQL UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

I miss the SET in your UPDATE statement. VALUES is used in INSERT statements.